# Fastest way to search RAM

Tags: fpga, ram, bram

I want to search RAM for a value, does anyone know which implementation will be the fastest. Im assuming that parallel search will be required.

My implementation would be to use a DeMux for each output of the RAM signal, the DeMux signal outputs then enter into NOR and AND gates. The select signal attaches to both NOR and AND gate inputs. And a group of final AND gates for the outputs of NOR and AND gates. Such that if the value to be searched is present on the DeMux, The RAM output is passed to either the NOR of AND gate where it calculates if its the same as the value to be compared to, if its the same outputs 1 if not outputs 0. AND gates are then used for full comparison.

Using this, i would start at an address in RAM, then increment till a 1 is found at the output of the last AND gate. I could implemented parallel reading by duplication the comparison structure and the RAM such that dual ports is available. I would then start at different addresses, this makes the comparison of the whole RAM faster.

The problem im facing is, im not sure where a full search will be possible before the next clock cycle. Mainly because there is a delay for the read and then the comparison circuit before the next memory address can be read. I then have to multiply this by the number of memory addresses and it should be less than the time period of clock cycle to satisfy for meta stability.

Does anyone know of a different search and comparison circuit?

Thanks

Comment: Consider DDR muxing with dual port

Comment: Hi could you explain what you mean? DDR interface muxing do you have an image thanks

Comment: If you REALLY need single-cycle search, look into Content Addressable Memory (CAM).

Comment: Have you ever considered CML logic family?

Comment: Searching linearly a value is wasteful. Is it impossible to organize your data so that it has some fast to search logical order which is built by software?

Comment: You did not specify type or size of RAM or any performance requirements.  You are correct in that whatever you implement will have an upper bound on performance.  This is always the case.  Ideally, the upper bound is better than your application requirement.  Parallel search, is essentially a CAM, as mentioned by Brian above.  This will chew up a ton of logic, and will really slow down your max clock rate.  That doesn't mean it's slower to complete the lookup than a linear search, though.  Software solutions often use hash tables for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming that parallel search will be required.

Usually, not. Such an operation is bandwidth limited, so searching in parallel just slows you down.
You'd go linear through all addresses. That's what the memory controller is most optimized for, if it's optimized for anything.

If the memory word contains multiple instances of values to be compared, you can of course do that comparison simultaneously.

If you can have *multiple independent RAM buses*, then, yeah, do one linear search on all.

Your description sounds very low-level (and a bit confusing). I don't think this'll bring you far; telling your synthesizer in the HDL of your choice that you're looking for `value_from_ram[i] == value_to_be_looked_for` will allow that to choose the appropriate technology mapping for you. This is an FPGA, it does not contain "NOR" or "AND" gates, but look-up tables with 2 to 6 inputs, depending on the type of FPGA, and hence, these minimal logic things are not what the technology can "natively" do.